# Merge sort Java implementation for an interview

Tags: java, algorithm, interview-questions, mergesort

I just learned Merge sort, and I really like this Merge sort implementation since it is very logical and very easy to follow. If I was asked in an interview to implement merge sort, will this implementation suffice?

I know creating those new arrays every time the `mergeSort()` method is called is bad practice. I fully understand merge sort, I can explain it in very good detail as I implement it, but will this implementation lose me some "points" because of the the way I am creating all these new arrays?

Are there any other things that may lose me some points?

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] a) {
    if(a.length < 2) return;

    int mid = a.length / 2;

    int[] left = new int[mid];
    int[] right = new int[a.length - mid];

    //Filling left and right arrays.
    for(int i = 0; i < left.length; i++)
        left[i] = a[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < right.length; i++)
        right[i] = a[i + mid];

    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    merge(left, right, a);
}

public static void merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] a) {
    int i = 0; //For left array
    int j = 0; //For right array
    int k = 0; //For a array

    while(i < left.length && j < right.length) {
        if(left[i] <= right[j])
            a[k++] = left[i++];
        else
            a[k++] = right[j++];
    }

    //Filling remaining integers, for the array that has left over numbers.
    while(i < left.length)
        a[k++] = left[i++];
    while(j < right.length)
        a[k++] = right[j++];

}
```

This is tested and working.

Comment: its a static method and it wont create a new array in the memory it will use the same static one.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If you ignore it is static, treat it like public void mergeSort(int[] a).

FIY, it was only static because I was writing in the main class. In practise it will be in its own class.

What is your comment now?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some thoughts on things you might improve:

Always use curly braces, even when they're optional. This is a common source of errors when existing code is modified.

`int i == 0; //For left array` should be `int leftArrayIndex = 0`. Don’t use a comment to label a variable .. use the variable’s name to do that. Same thing for `j` and `k`.

`mid` should be midpoint, perhaps? `originalArray` instead of `a`? Variable names should be clear and descriptive. Avoid abbreviations where possible.

Almost all Java style guides put a space between `if`, `for`, or `while` and their opening paren. This easily differentiates them from method calls.

Variables that don’t change should be declared final.

Learn and use the libraries. In particular, `System.arraycopy()` is preferable to looping to manually copy array entries.

`merge` should be private, not public.